# What is there an inconsistent use of tabs and spaces?

Tags: python

The error reads:

```
dhcp-169-233-163-147:Desktop juliushamilton$ python3 printTrie.py
  File "printTrie.py", line 16
    matchbuild(daughter, next(base))
                                                                           ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

My code reads:

```
def matchbuild(node, base):
    match = False
    if base == False:
       return
    for daughter in node.daughters:
        if base == node.edge:
            match = True 
            matchbuild(daughter, next(base))
    if match == False:
       trie.append(Node(node, [], base))
       matchbuild(node, base)
```

I wanted to put the for/if section as a one-liner, but the execution also raised an error here. 
What could be wrong with the spacing?

Comment: Most of your lines start with spaces then indent with tabs.

Comment: If you are editing in vi, put these lines in your .vimrc:  `set tabstop=4` and `set et`  They will improve your life by allowing you to use the tab key but get four spaces.

Comment: after implementing @ncmathsadist's suggestions, close the file and open it again.  Then type `:%retab!` to apply the new space characters throughout your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is as the stacktrace indicates, you are using either tabs or spaces at other places for indentation , but in the line -

```
matchbuild(daughter, next(base))
```

You are using the opposite thing (like you may be using spaces to indicate indentation in other lines , but then you used tabs to indicate the indentation for this line. In Python 3.x , you cannot mix tabs and spaces , you have to use a consistent thing throughout your script. I believe it is recommended to use 4 spaces to indicate a level of indentation.